# How to set useragent as QuickTime in Python script?

Tags: python, user-agent

The server only allows access to the videos if the useragent is QT, how to add it to this script ?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from os import pardir, rename, listdir, getcwd
from os.path import join
from urllib import urlopen, urlretrieve, FancyURLopener
class MyOpener(FancyURLopener):
    version = 'QuickTime/7.6.2 (verqt=7.6.2;cpu=IA32;so=Mac 10.5.8)'

def main():
# Set up file paths.
data_dir = 'data'
ft_path = join(data_dir, 'titles.txt')
fu_path = join(data_dir, 'urls.txt')

# Open the files
try:
    f_titles = open(ft_path, 'r')
    f_urls = open(fu_path, 'r')
except:
    print "Make sure titles.txt and urls.txt are in the data directory."
    exit()

# Read file contents into lists.
titles = []
urls = []
for l in f_titles:
    titles.append(l)
for l in f_urls:
    urls.append(l)

# Create a dictionary and download the files.
downloads = dict(zip(titles, urls))
for title, url in downloads.iteritems():
    fpath = join(data_dir, title.strip().replace('\t',"").replace(" ", "_"))
    fpath += ".mov"
    urlretrieve(url, fpath)

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

*Ignore this, text to fill the posting restriction. blablablabla*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually described in [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib._urlopener). Your code should look something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import urllib

from os import pardir, rename, listdir, getcwd
from os.path import join


class MyOpener(urllib.FancyURLopener):
     version = 'QuickTime/7.6.2 (verqt=7.6.2;cpu=IA32;so=Mac 10.5.8)'

# This line tells urllib.urlretrieve and urllib.urlopen to use your MyOpener 
# instead of the default urllib.FancyOpener
urllib._urlopener = MyOpener()

def main():
    # lots of stuff
    for title, url in downloads.iteritems():
        fpath = join(data_dir, title.strip().replace('\t',"").replace(" ", "_"))
        fpath += ".mov"
        urllib.urlretrieve(url, fpath)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change it like this:

http://wolfprojects.altervista.org/changeua.php

Then try:

```
opener = MyOpener()
opener.retrieve(url, fpath)
```

Instead of using urllib directly and that should do the trick.

(I am not sure why overriding urllib internals does not work, but they are internals and poking them is not guaranteened to work :( )

Also more info here:

http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.URLopener

Comment: I did the following but files are still not downloading `from urllib import urlopen, urlretrieve, FancyURLopener
class MyOpener(FancyURLopener):
 version = 'QuickTime/7.6.2 (verqt=7.6.2;cpu=IA32;so=Mac 10.5.8)'`

Comment: Please post full source cod e what you are doing - otherwise it is not possible to help

Comment: It is full source. Other files are just URLS and titles.

Comment: I don't see class MyOpener(FancyURLopener) in the source - it cannot be full source

Comment: Your source code does not follow Python syntax indentation and whitespace rules. Please study Python basics http://docs.python.org/tutorial/ before trying to write code in Python.

Comment: Good joke... why do you think I posted this question ? Indentation is fine, the scripts runs without error. It's this site that doesn't format well.

Comment: Sorry... you didn't deserve that. I was just little tired and not feeling well after the quality of the questions pouring on this site. I edited my answer to be more helpful now.